# Extracting a substring based on a pattern

Tags: vba, excel

As part of a project to pull data from our purchasing system (Sage) back into our quoting system (an Excel template) to automate variations to existing quotes, I wanted to grab the original quote number from the Sage listing.

Different members of the purchasing team key the quote number into the sales order in different ways, such as "Refers to quote 11111AA", "Quote ref 22222BB", "Quote number 33333CC refers", and so on. It is however always entered into the first line of the sales order. The quote number is always five digits followed by two letters.

We have a spreadsheet which queries Sage and returns all the sales orders for a particular job. The quote number is therefore always somewhere in a particular cell (K2 if anyone cares) of the spreadsheet.

This function takes a target "CheckCell" and a pattern "Pattern" and returns the part of the target cell that matches the pattern. "Pattern" is in the normal "like" format, so for my example I use "#####[A-Z][A-Z]".

```
Function FindQNo(CheckCell As Range, Pattern As String) As String

    Dim Target As Variant
    Target = Split(CheckCell.Value, " ")
    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(Target) To UBound(Target)
        If Target(i) Like Pattern Then FindQNo = Target(i)
    Next

End Function
```

Comment: I recommend changing your `If` statement to exit the loop when you get a match: `If Target(i) Like Pattern Then; FindQNo = Target(i); Exit For; End If`

Comment: Good call - I was being lazy.

Comment: @AndiAllan  You're right that was I careless oversight on my part.   Add the Exit For like Peter said and your code is perfect.

Comment: Thank you - I have updated with the exit for. I've separately asked a related question in Overflow as I'd like to make this code more flexible.